# SharePoint online Appwebproxy.aspx threshold limit in IE browser in SharePoint Hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have one SharePoint Hosted app and I have cross domain call inside it. I have problem related to threshold limit in appwebproxy.aspx in IE browser only but in chrome and Mozilla it is working as expected.

Note: when I open developer tool inside IE above error is not coming and working as expected.